# Uncaught ReferenceError: ReconnectingWebSocket is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, electron

I'm working on developing a chat program using Javascript, and the ElectronJS. However, I have this problem:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ReconnectingWebSocket is not defined
>      at conectaServidorSockets (teste.js:9)
>      at HTMLButtonElement.fazConexao (teste.js:62)

I've tried everything and I do not know how to solve it. it's a college job.

```
var socket;
function O(X)
    {
    return document.getElementById(X);
    }
function conectaServidorSockets (url,  nome)
{
    socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(url);

    socket.onopen = function(evt) {
    console.log('Conectou no servidor'); 
    var m = {tipo:'login',valor:nome};
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(m));   

    }
    socket.onclose = function(evt) {
    console.log('foi desconectado do servidor');
    }
    socket.onmessage = function(evt) {

        var tmp = evt.data;

        tmp = JSON.parse(tmp);
        switch (tmp.tipo)
        {
            case 'todosUsuarios':
                console.log('todosUsuarios');
                console.log(tmp.valor);

                for (let a=0;a<tmp.valor.length;a++)
                {
                    document.getElementById('lista-conectados').innerHTML =document.getElementById('lista conectados').innerHTML+'<br>'+tmp.valor[a]; 
                }
                break;

            case 'usuarioNovo':
                console.log('usuarioNovo');
                console.log(tmp.valor);
                document.getElementById('lista-conectados').innerHTML =document.getElementById('lista-conectados').innerHTML+'<br>'+tmp.valor; 

                break;
            case 'texto':
                document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML =document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML+'<br>'+tmp.valor;
                break;
        }
    }

}
function enviaMSG()
{
    var conteudo = document.getElementById('valorMSG').value;
    var m = {tipo:'MSG',valor:conteudo};
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(m));
}
function fazConexao()
{
    O('identificacao').style.display='none';
    var nome = O('nome').value;
    conectaServidorSockets('ws://'+window.location.hostname+':10000', nome);

    var salva = {ID:nome,PASS:''};
    localStorage.setItem('meusSettings',JSON.stringify(salva));

}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getElementById('botao').addEventListener('click',enviaMSG);
    document.getElementById('conecta').  
    addEventListener('click',fazConexao);

    var cfg = localStorage.getItem('meusSettings');
    if (cfg)
    {
    alert("Tem informacoes salvas");

    }
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket/issues/94

Answer (score 0):

It's my solution. It's worked for me goodly.

Add this [script reconnecting-websocket.min.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket/master/reconnecting-websocket.min.js) in your local file
and include your project.

```
<script src="./YOUR_FILE_NAME.js"></script>
```